# Custom NSOperations autorelease pool

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsautoreleasepool

I have implemented some custom subclasses of `NSOperation` to use within a queue.

Where should (or could) I set up the `@autoreleasepool`?

Within my custom operation's `main` method?

Or around the statement where I add my operation to the queue instance?

EDIT:

What if I am adding operations with blocks? Should `@autoreleasepool` go in the block as well?

I am using ARC if that is of relevance.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason to use autorelease pools is to prevent a huge aggregation of temporary unneeded objects. For instance, suppose your operation opens a bunch of images, extracts out some pieces of them (saved in NSData objects), then as a final step converts the new pieces to images.

What I would do in that case is put the opening and extracting piece in an autorelease pool (insuring the NSData objects were properly retained), then exit that before creating and saving the new images. That way, all the images that were opened get released for sure.

There is no reason I know of to generally use an autorelease pool in an operation, as once the operation finished the queue most like does it then or shortly afterwards.

In fact, with ARC, the compiler will sometimes pull object out of autorelease pools, retain then, then release them directly when not needed.

Unless you have a known pressing need for a pool, I would not use one. Now, if you use a concurrent NSOperation with a 'start' method, that's a different story and you should wrap the code around the runloop with a pool.